# looping to find sum of array java

Tags: java, arrays, class, loops, sum

I am making program that adds up the values from an array of a class. I keep getting an error about binary operators. My code is:

```
public static int sum(Array[] x){
   int sum = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
       sum += x[i];
   }
   return sum;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please include the full stacktrace. and shouldn't `Array[] x` be `int[] x`?

Comment: What does your `Array` class look like?

Answer (score 4):

It seems you are using an `Array[]`, and there is no `operator+` for the type `Array` (which is the type of `x[i]`)

You probably wanted `int[]` as the type of `x`.

```
public static int sum(int[] x){
//                     ^^
//               note the fixed type of the array
   int sum = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
       sum += x[i];
   }
   return sum;
}
```

---

**Bonus**: For simplicity and readability - you might want to consider using a [for-each loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)

```
public static int sum(int[] x){
       int sum = 0;
       for (int e : x){
           sum += e;
       }
       return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your parameter is an array with type Array.
What are you expecting to see an int "+" an Array object?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use int[] and not Array[] which is a generic type.